# Create Session with JWT

Tags: rest-api, authentication, single-sign-on

I'm currently working on a shop like project that uses React as frontend and Wordpress with Woocommerce as a backend.

To authenticate with the API I use the [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/), which works great.

The problem I'm facing is that I want to redirect to a checkout page that is not part of the PWA but a traditional Wordpress page. Is there any way that I can create a WP session using the JWT token I created for the API?

The alternative would be to store the login data and pass it on to the checkout page. But I'd rather avoid this because of security concerns.

Comment: You could either post it a 'log me in' endpoint, and even use the existing login mechanism if you create an 'authenticate' filter that unpacks the token and returns the user if appropriate - see e.g. wp_authenticate_username_password as an example you can build on. Or you could save the token in a cookie and override the determine_current_user filter to use this as the session cookie, in the same way that wp_validate_logged_in_cookie does. Apologies I don't know the specifics: hopefully someone can write one or both of these up properly as an answer.

Comment: You can use the user id to login the user, or extend a new token with the claims you need in your checkout page.